# Need a Javascript example that rotates SWF every day

Tags: javascript, rotation, flash, banner

I have a seven swf banners that I must rotate them every day. Let's say, 1.swf for monday, 2.swf for tuesday, etc. All the swf files will be on an external source and the javascript cod will be on client website. 
I want to make an javascript that load the swf banners like in the above examples. Any suggestion?
Thanks!

Comment: Have't tried anything yet because i don't know where to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simplest solution (you may want to enhance that):

```
var date = new Date();
var day = date.getDay();
var file = day + ".swf";
var url = "someDir/" + file;
var el = document.getElementById('banner');
el.src = url;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/27ewmpsb/

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will implement this!

Answer (score 0):

Just get the daynumber `(0-6)` with javascript. And use that number to build the url to your swf. Be aware that you can run into cross domain errors when trying to load swf files from different servers (if I remember correctly)

```
//0=sunday, 1=monday, 2=tuesday, etc
var today= new Date();
var daynumber = today.getDay();
console.log(daynumber);
```